# NO_RESET flag not working in amazon device farm(Appium)

Tags: amazon-web-services, appium, aws-device-farm

NO_RESET flag not working in amazon device farm(Appium). I used the following code in my capabilities.

capabilities.setCapability("noReset", true);

Answer (score 1):

You can find the answer in this line of official `aws-device-farm-appium` code sample: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-device-farm-appium-tests-for-sample-app/blob/master/src/test/java/Tests/AbstractBaseTests/TestBase.java#L66

> We do not need to and SHOULD NOT set our own DesiredCapabilities

That basically means that your manually provided capability is **ignored**.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NO_RESET,"true");
```

This should work.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the code, it worked on real device and not on AWS.